# disk full: unable to install software packages

Tags: disk-usage

I am trying to download a huge python package and suddenly I hit this space crunch issue. When I run `df -h` command, it shows:

```
[root@darwin ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       5.0G  5.0G  0.0G 100% /
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G   17M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

I can see only `/dev/vda1` has reached 100% of its capacity. But the other filesystems are free, why can't they be used for package installation?

Comment: Whenever I hit this problem it's usually a log file that is growing exponentially. Delete the log file then fix the problem. But your issue may just be that 5 gigs is too small

Comment: If you can't free up space, ask if your hosting service can increase the amount of disk space while keeping your existing files intact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`devtmpfs` contains nodes which are populated by the kernel with information about devices, etc.

`tmpfs` is actually stored in memory even though it appears as a mounted file system. The contents of `tmpfs` can be swapped out to the swap space but it will all disappear when the system is rebooted.

You can probably clear some space but that's only a temporary solution as logs, data, and installing more packages will only fill it up once again. 5GB just isn't enough space in the longterm.

The only way to permanently resolve your issue is to add more permanent storage space to your system.

Answer (score 2):

A 5GB disk is not big but can even though have Linux distribution with GUI and a number of standard application.

You should find out which directory uses most of the disk space. Use **Disk Usage** `du` for that:

```
du -smx / | sort -n
```

The last directory in that list uses mos space.

E.g. it could be `/var`. Then run the more detailed command:

```
du -m /var | sort -n
```

As an example, one can see that `/var/cache/apt/archives` takes up 418MB:

```
418     /var/cache/apt/archives
472     /var/cache/apt
482     /var/cache
706     /var
```

When you have found the directory which uses most space you might delete som files from that:

```
sudo rm /foo/bar
```

If your distribution is a Debian like distro you can remove already installed packages with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: Also check out ncdu, a very nice command line tool for visualising where your space has gone.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, the main reason those filesystems can't be used for package installation because they're not mounted where package files go (typically split between /etc and /usr). Analyzing your df -h:

```
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
```

This is used to keep track of devices via their filesystem pointers. Packages don't go in /dev. Ideally only devices go in /dev.

```
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G   17M  7.9G   1% /run
```

These are all different temporary filesystems, located in `/dev/shm` ("shared memory") and `/run`.

```
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

This, like /dev, has a very specific purpose, which is beyond the scope of this answer to even begin to describe.

```
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

This is one last tmpfs that's designated specifically for the root user (uid 0).

None of these would be good candidates for package installation anyway because when you reboot their contents are emptied. It's conceivable that you could just store package archives on the disk and do an overlay tmpfs and reinstall all packages every boot, but chances are if you only have 5GB of storage it's an embedded device and that would take a very long time to boot if you did that. It would be a neat project though.